# GDB : How to display the value around the equal sign automatically after every sentence executed

Tags: gdb

I am using gdb. I get a trouble that how to display the value around the equal sign automatically after every sentence executed. Printing the variables manually is inconvenient .
Thanks !

Comment: Use gdb `display` command: http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html#Auto-Display

Comment: The display command needs the specific expression as parameter, but I want to display any expression around the equal sign for just one time after the expression executed.